# How to avoid response maniputaion for OTP verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, security, one-time-password

I have OTP verification functionality & front end(React JS) is sending request to Backend(rails) and depending on response I'm setting mobile verified as true or false on front end.

Success response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"success":true}
```

Unprocessable Entity response:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

{"success":false}
```

When user is getting unprocessable entity, user is changing the response using Burp Suite & sending modified response to front end

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"success":true}
```

Front end has logic to set mobile verified on received response only.

Thought of adding OTP in response & verifying it on front end but user can also stub that.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What difference does setting the mobile verified make on the client?

Comment: @GaborLengyel User is using others mobile number without their interaction

Answer (score -1):

You have to protect the channel with TLS (HTTPS), so no third party can change the data without your knowledge. All other means of protection you can implement are secondary as related to this.